# iOS load from xib not works

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I have created a Custom View Controller with XIB file.

In XIB file, I put a tableview and a slider to the view and connect all of them as IBOutlet to the File's Owner.

I check the File's owner class and it is my custom class, so it's ok.

I double checked the view and slider are connected with File's Owner.

But when I try to load my custom viewcontroller, I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NoteController 0x6bd1da0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _slider.'
```

Slider is my IBOutlet (which is connected to the view controller)

I found a lot of same problems on the internet, but all solutions not works for me :(

The load code:

```
NSArray *xibViews=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"PopoverSetFont" owner:self options:nil];
```

What should I try?

Comment: Can you show the declaration for the outlet? Does your nib or the view controller have any compiler warnings?

Comment: See the solution in question. I just found now.

Comment: It is allowed you post your own answer and accept it then.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer (don't put it in the question, make an answer / response to your own Q - this is encouraged in the SO community as @Didier points out).  This will not only clearly mark your answer as an answer clearly, but it will also allow you to accept it as an answer and stop people from coming to this Q since no answer has been accepted.

Comment: Ok, I know it, but I cant answer to my question, just after X (maybe 8?) hours. So I do that now, but I can't accept my own question today, only tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

After 2 hours, and when I ask this question, found a problem. I do not delete a question, I share it, I hope it helps.

So instead of the [[NSBundle mainBundle]... line, use this for load:

```
PopoverSetFont *popoverView=[[PopoverSetFont alloc]initWithNibName:@"PopoverSetFont" bundle:nil];
```